# How to fit points in a picture using locators

Tags: dynamic, fitting, locator

I've got a problem doing some analysis work on some of my spectra. I am basically looking for features that look like parabolas.
In need of a tool to quickly find two parabolas in a spectrum (they are in form of pictures), I came up with this solution:

```
l1 = Graphics[{Darker[Red, 0.5], Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i/2], {i, 3}], 
Line[{{0.1, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.1, -0.25}, {0.1, -1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.25, -0.1}, {1.75, -0.1}}], 
Line[{{-0.25, -0.1}, {-1.75, -0.1}}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
l2 = Graphics[{Darker[Green, 0.5], Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i/2], {i, 3}],
 Line[{{0.1, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.1, -0.25}, {0.1, -1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.25, -0.1}, {1.75, -0.1}}], 
Line[{{-0.25, -0.1}, {-1.75, -0.1}}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
mod = a*(y + e)^2 + d;
data = Import["choose any picture in the form of .png"];

DynamicModule[{pt11 = {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4, 
3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}, 
pt12 = {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/2, ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/2},
pt13 = {3*ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4, 
3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}, 
pt21 = {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4 + 50, 
3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}, 
pt22 = {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/2 + 50, 
ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/2}, 
pt23 = {3*ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4 + 50, 
3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}},
Dynamic[Show[data, 
Plot[NonlinearModelFit[{pt11, pt12, pt13}, mod, {a, d, e}, y][
 x], {x, 0, ImageDimensions[data][[2]]}, 
PlotRange -> {0, ImageDimensions[data][[1]] - 80}, 
PlotStyle -> Lighter[Red, 0.5]], 
Plot[NonlinearModelFit[{pt21, pt22, pt23}, mod, {a, d, e}, y][
 x], {x, 0, ImageDimensions[data][[2]]}, 
PlotRange -> {0, ImageDimensions[data][[1]] - 80}, 
PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, 0.5]], {Graphics[
 Locator[Dynamic[pt11], l1]], 
Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt12], l1]], 
Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt13], l1]]}, {Graphics[
 Locator[Dynamic[pt21], l2]], 
Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt22], l2]], 
Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[pt23], l2]]}]]]
```

It works, but not good and is awfully slow. Any idea of how to do the same thing, but better? :)
Thanks a lot!

Thanks fpr that comment. The spectra look somewhat like this:
[image: Spectrum taken from a publication (http://iopscience.iop.org/1367-2630/9/10/391/fulltext/)]

Comment: Have you tried "getcoordinates" and then doing an approximation?

Comment: Not yet. I am still hoping to do it as interactively as in my posted code. Using GetCoordinates, I only see how to do it with two evaluation steps.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange! It would be good if you could provide a sample image of a spectrum. It would be easier to understand what the parabolas are for then, which could affect quality of the answers you may get (or not get, since you've already answered your own question, but still.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could be shorter:

```
loc[col_] := Graphics[{Darker[col, 0.5], Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i/2], {i, 3}], 
                      Table[Rotate[Line[{{0.1, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.75}}], t, {0, 0}], {t, 0 , 2 Pi, Pi/2}]},
                      ImageSize -> 20];
mod = a*(# + e)^2 + d &;
data = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmQLj.png", ImageSize -> 300];
id = ImageDimensions@data;

man[col_] := Manipulate[
  fit = Quiet@Solve[Thread[Equal[(mod /@ pt[[All, 1]]), pt[[All, 2]]]], {a, e,  d}];
  Show[data, Plot[mod@x /. fit, {x, 0, id[[1]]},  PlotStyle -> Lighter[col, 0.5]], PlotLabel -> {fit}],
  {{pt, RandomInteger[Min @@ id, {3, 2}]}, Locator, Appearance -> loc[col]}, 
  {{fit, {}}, ControlType -> None}]

Row[{man[Red], man[Green]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I do not fully understand everything the code does, but the result looks good. Have you tested, if it's running quicker than my second solution? So far, I like it better that I can see both parabolas in one fit, since I am interested in the intersecting point of both. (I am though aware, that this is easily implementable in your code as well. ;) )

Comment: @DominikJungkenn Faster? There are no performance issues there. The calculations are very simple.

Comment: My first version had big performance issues. The second one runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know it's strange to answer my own question, but I hope other people with similar problems will appreciate this:
I found a way to have the same functionality that runs much much quicker, using Manipulate (which I wanted to avoid in the first attemot, because I thought DynamicModule would get faster results :) ) So here is the code that works fine for me:

```
l1 = Graphics[{Darker[Red, 0.5], Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i/2], {i, 3}], 
Line[{{0.1, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.1, -0.25}, {0.1, -1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.25, -0.1}, {1.75, -0.1}}], 
Line[{{-0.25, -0.1}, {-1.75, -0.1}}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
l2 = Graphics[{Darker[Green, 0.5], Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i/2], {i, 3}],
Line[{{0.1, 0.25}, {0.1, 1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.1, -0.25}, {0.1, -1.75}}], 
Line[{{0.25, -0.1}, {1.75, -0.1}}], 
Line[{{-0.25, -0.1}, {-1.75, -0.1}}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
mod = a*(y + e)^2 + d;
data = Import["EinBild.png"];
Manipulate[
fit1 = NonlinearModelFit[{pt11, pt12, pt13}, mod, {a, d, e}, y];
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[{pt21, pt22, pt23}, mod, {a, d, e}, y];
Show[data, 
Plot[fit1[x], {x, 0, ImageDimensions[data][[2]]},PlotRange -> {0,ImageDimensions[data][[1]] - 80},PlotStyle -> Lighter[Red, 0.5]],
Plot[fit2[x], {x, 0,ImageDimensions[data][[2]]},PlotRange -> {0,ImageDimensions[data][[1]] - 80},PlotStyle -> Lighter[Green, 0.5]]],
{{pt11, {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4,3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}},{1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]],ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l1},
{{pt12, {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/2,ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/2}}, {1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]], ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l1},
{{pt13, {3*ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4,3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}}, {1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]], ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l1},
{{pt21, {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4 + 50,3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}}, {1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]], ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l2},
{{pt22, {ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/2 + 50,ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/2}}, {1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]], ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l2},
{{pt23, {3*ImageDimensions[data][[2]]/4 + 50,3*ImageDimensions[data][[1]]/4}}, {1,1},{ImageDimensions[data][[2]], ImageDimensions[data][[1]]},Locator, Appearance -> l2}]
```